# How to scrape data from website with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cheerio

I am trying to scrape the Ark: Survival Evolved wiki with no success. Nested elements and same class-name elements throwing me off.
https://ark.gamepedia.com/Pteranodon

Have tried searching the forums and cannot find the answer to my problem.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const $dossier = $('.info-framework');
const $domestication = $dossier.find('div:nth-child(4)');
```

i manage to grab the div that contains the content i need, but everything i try from here ends in undefined. specifically i am trying to grab the "tameable", "rideable" & "breedable" elements. If someone could point me in the right direction, or show me how to grab the data so i could then learn and hopefully grab the rest of the data i need that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some example you can build up on:

```js
const abilities = Array.from($('.info-unit').eq(6).find('.info-X3-33')).map(element => element.innerText)
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: After testing this i am receiving an array of 6 undefined items. had a little play with the values and i just cannot get it working.

Comment: See the screenshot